# WebpackDevServer with `--max-old-space-size=32000` flag sometimes consumes more ram than onboard, but crashes before requesting Swap RAM

Tags: node.js, unix, webpack, webpack-dev-server, ram

I'm trying to run an enormously complicated React application using WebpackDevServer. I'll include the config details below, but in short I'm running the `new WebpackDevServer(compiler, config).listen()` command.

Sometimes, this successfully runs the app. Oftentimes though, the app will crash and fail to start with `FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`.

I either run the app via `yarn start --max-old-space-size=32000` or `node scripts/start.js --max-old-space-size=32000`. I wasn't sure if `yarn` was correctly passing CLI args. My package.json, in short, looks like:

**package.json**

```
{
    ...
    scripts: {
      "start": "node scripts/start.js",
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If I have very little software running on this machine, the command usually works. However, if I have other applications, the server crashes with error above.

I observe my RAM usage with `watch -n1 free -m` as I run the app. The output looks like:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15212        8090        5753          39        1734        7121
Swap:          24450        4915       19535
```

Right now, with only 5753 MB of RAM available on hardware, I observe the webpackdevserver over the course of 1 minute consuming more and more RAM until `free` under `Mem:` gets to around 200MB, at which point the above error occurs. At no point does `free` under `Swap:` change. If I close many other applications, I can usually get the webpackdevserver to run successfully, with around 1GB of RAM available. I get strange results with other programs taking `Mem` or `Swap`, sometimes taking only enough `Mem` for the webpackdevserver to not crash before moving to take `Swap`, other times taking too much `Mem` and triggering node to crash.

**Is there some way I can ensure node allocates Swap space, rather than simply crashing when running out of memory?**

My full start script is:

```
'use strict';

process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'development';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
    throw err;
});

require('../config/env');

const fs = require('fs');
const chalk = require('react-dev-utils/chalk');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const clearConsole = require('react-dev-utils/clearConsole');
const checkRequiredFiles = require('react-dev-utils/checkRequiredFiles');
const {
    choosePort,
    createCompiler,
    prepareProxy,
    prepareUrls,
} = require('react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils');
const semver = require('semver');
const paths = require('../config/paths');
const configFactory = require('../config/webpack.config');
const createDevServerConfig = require('../config/webpackDevServer.config');
const getClientEnvironment = require('../config/env');
const react = require(require.resolve('react', { paths: [paths.appPath] }));

const env = getClientEnvironment(paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1));
const useYarn = fs.existsSync(paths.yarnLockFile);
const isInteractive = process.stdout.isTTY;

if (!checkRequiredFiles([paths.appHtml, paths.appIndexJs])) {
    process.exit(1);
}

const DEFAULT_PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const HOST = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';

if (process.env.HOST) {
    console.log(
        chalk.cyan(
            `Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: ${chalk.yellow(
                chalk.bold(process.env.HOST)
            )}`
        )
    );
    console.log(
        `If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell.`
    );
    console.log(
        `Learn more here: ${chalk.yellow('https://cra.link/advanced-config')}`
    );
    console.log();
}

const { checkBrowsers } = require('react-dev-utils/browsersHelper');
checkBrowsers(paths.appPath, isInteractive)
    .then(() => {
        return choosePort(HOST, DEFAULT_PORT);
    })
    .then((port) => {
        if (port == null) {
            return;
        }

        const config = configFactory('development');
        const protocol = process.env.HTTPS === 'true' ? 'https' : 'http';
        const appName = require(paths.appPackageJson).name;

        const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);
        const tscCompileOnError = process.env.TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR === 'true';
        const urls = prepareUrls(
            protocol,
            HOST,
            port,
            paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1)
        );
        const devSocket = {
            warnings: (warnings) =>
                devServer.sockWrite(devServer.sockets, 'warnings', warnings),
            errors: (errors) =>
                devServer.sockWrite(devServer.sockets, 'errors', errors),
        };
        const compiler = createCompiler({
            appName,
            config,
            devSocket,
            urls,
            useYarn,
            useTypeScript,
            tscCompileOnError,
            webpack,
        });
        const proxySetting = require(paths.appPackageJson).proxy;
        const proxyConfig = prepareProxy(
            proxySetting,
            paths.appPublic,
            paths.publicUrlOrPath
        );
        const serverConfig = createDevServerConfig(
            proxyConfig,
            urls.lanUrlForConfig
        );
        const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, serverConfig);
        devServer.listen(port, HOST, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            if (isInteractive) {
                clearConsole();
            }

            if (env.raw.FAST_REFRESH && semver.lt(react.version, '16.10.0')) {
                console.log(
                    chalk.yellow(
                        `Fast Refresh requires React 16.10 or higher. You are using React ${react.version}.`
                    )
                );
            }

            console.log(chalk.cyan('Starting the development server...\n'));
        });

        ['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'].forEach(function (sig) {
            process.on(sig, function () {
                devServer.close();
                process.exit();
            });
        });

        if (process.env.CI !== 'true') {
            process.stdin.on('end', function () {
                devServer.close();
                process.exit();
            });
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        if (err && err.message) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

System information:

```
[caleb@caleb-manjaro ui]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: ManjaroLinux
Description:    Manjaro Linux
Release:    23.0.0
Codename:   Uranos
```

(I've added the tag unix-utils believing that, in my unix-like environment of Manjaro, there may be tooling there that will allow me to get the desired behavior from node)